# phpMyAdmin prevent sql substitution in views

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I create views in phpMyAdmin, the asterisk (*) that indicates all fields is substituted by the field names.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior; it's part of [MySQL's view handling to freeze the structure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) when the view is created. New columns added after the view's creation aren't automatically added to the view, because the view is stored in MySQL with the individual columns defined rather than with a wildcard.

Comment: Although this might be for good reason, it is annoying that fields are not automatically added, and views get broken after deleting or renaming of fields.